# Apache IMPALA - How to count how often a special pattern exists in a string and sum up the values behind until a delimeter

Tags: sql, impala

Hello I have a column which stores a delimated string:

| mycolumn |
| --- |
| 310006551-1= 1|310006551-2= 1 |
| 310006551-1= 1 |
| 310008951-1= 2|319687525-2= 3 |
| 317653646-1= 5|312356897-2= 1 |

How can I write a statement where the numbers behind '= ' get summed up?

| mycolumn_qty |
| --- |
| 2 |
| 2 |
| 5 |
| 6 |

I have tried with `split_part()` and `regexp_extract()` , but this wont give me the desired output.